# Why this constructor which imitates `vector`'s initialization from iterators can work?

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I use C++17, and I try to implement a fixed-length array whose length is determined at runtime. After consulting some information, I choose to implement it by privately inheriting `std::vector`. This is the code:

```
template <typename T>
class FixedVector : private vector<T> {
 public:
  explicit FixedVector(size_t n, T t = {}) : vector<T>(n, t) {}

  template <typename It>
  FixedVector(It IteratorBegin, It IteratorEnd)
      : vector<T>(IteratorBegin, IteratorEnd) {}

  using vector<T>::begin;
  using vector<T>::end;
  using vector<T>::cbegin;
  using vector<T>::cend;
  using vector<T>::rbegin;
  using vector<T>::rend;
  using vector<T>::crbegin;
  using vector<T>::crend;

  using vector<T>::front;
  using vector<T>::back;
  using vector<T>::operator[];
  using vector<T>::data;
  using vector<T>::at;

  using vector<T>::size;
};
```

The second constructor is to imitate the constructor of vector, allowing us to copy construct the current fixed-length container from iterators of another container with the same intrinsic element type.
I have three questions:

1. Why is the second constructor in my way of writing legal? It seems that the class template parameter `T` I specified is not related to the function template parameter `It`, shouldn’t the compiler report an error?
2. Is there a better and more elegant way to make my class have all other `vector`'s constructors where size is determined at initilization?
3. Is there a better and more elegant solution to achieve my needs? (that is, a continuous memory container whose size is determined at runtime, and its size cannot be modified afterwards, but you can still manipulate its elements)

Comment: 1. It is a valid syntactically, not semantically.  The way it is now it will even try to accept non iterator types (let alone an iterator for your class).
2. Look at std::vector documentation, there just are a lot of overloads.
3. Yes use std::array. 
And I really won't recommend deriving classes from standard library classes at all. If you need to extend use aggregation and just take the little pain of some explicit typing and forwarding.

Comment: use `using vector<T>::vector` to inherit the vector constructors.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Re: 3. Using `std::array` with sizes determined at runtime is going to be hard. Using `std::vector` is probably the best choice here.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I missed the runtime part... oops ;)

Comment: Unrelated: `class FixedVector : private vector<T>` implies that you've done `using std::vector;` in your header file (or worse, `using namespace std;`) which will affect every user of your header file. Please don't.

Comment: Side note on [Flexible array](https://youtu.be/IAdLwUXRUvg?t=889) you are trying to implement.

Comment: Do you know about the Google project [Abseil](https://abseil.io/)? It has lots of free C++ source code, including this [fixed-size array](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/absl/container/fixed_array.h) that has its size specified at runtime. Having never used Abseil myself, I am not in a position to say much, but I do notice a raft of includes in the file I have linked. Looks like there is a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: btw "a continuous memory container whose size is determined at runtime, and its size cannot be modified afterwards" is `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` or arguably `std::pair<size_t, std::unique_ptr<T[]>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be controversial, but I don't think there is a better way to do this in C++, at least if you *insist on basing your implementation in `std::vector`*.
After all, you want something based on `std::vector`, but it is not a *substitute* for it in general, so private inheritance is ok.

People say, "prefer a private member over inheritance," but that makes things worst because you have to replicate the members in a more verbose way, so all the `using vector<T>::member;` are ok.

To answer your detailed questions:

1. The second constructor is not illegal, `It` will be deduced from where the constructor is called regardless of `T`.

NOTE ADDED: Taking anything is perfectly fine. This is what most containers do. If you want to restrict it to "iterators that make sense," you have to be very careful not to over-restrict the interface. For example, you don't want just an iterator with value `T` but probably something more general, like iterators with values that are *convertible* to `T` or that can be used to construct `T`. It might to worth it, but here is a possibility:

```
template <typename It, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, std::std::iterator_traits<T>::reference> >
  FixedVector(It IteratorBegin, It IteratorEnd)
      : vector<T>(IteratorBegin, IteratorEnd) {}
```

(code not tested)

Even if you use C++20 concepts instead of `std::enable_if`, you must be careful what you demand from `It`.

You only gain by doing this if other constructors can compete for overload resolution, and you want to control that.

2. Yes, if you want *all* constructors from the base (which is appropriate, it seems), you can say `using vector<T>::vector;`.
3. Yes, you have a good proof of concept; but if I were you, I would not base my implementation on `std::vector` since it is too general, and you have to be careful not *to leak* the abstraction and allow a change of size or something like this. This is harder than it looks (for example, imagine that a `friend` could break the invariant).
   I would choose a more basic thing with less "baggage"; for example, `FixedVector` could be based on `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` and have a careful implementation of it.

I would call what you are trying to do "inheritance for restriction" (as opposed to "inheritance for extension" or "for polymorphism").
This is usually a symptom that the system lacks some intermediate classes with weaker abstractions.
In fact, it would even make sense to derive (publicly) `std::vector` from a hypothetical `std::FixedVector` without violating the Liskov principle.

Final note: I am sure some libraries do this, in Boost for example.
Or you can use this library (disclaimer: of mine) https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi .
It has a class for the particular case of `1`-dimensional arrays that is used as `multi::static_array<T, 1> arr(size);` and the size will be fixed.
Although the focus is avoiding iterator invalidation and generalization to multiple dimensions, it doesn't support move for example.

Comment: I generally agree, but one point is this: A friend function or class could break any invariant of any class, not just this one. So I find it a bad argument against OPs design. And what is the baggage of `std::vector`? Is it the extra _capacity_ pointer? The additional member functions that resize the vector have been carefully left out of the public interface of `FixedVector`. I think it's a great design overall.

Comment: @chrysante, it was just an example. A friend could simply do `.resize` in the current implementation. For other implementations on "less powerful" implementations, the friend would have to work more to break the invariant. Of course, a friend that breaks the invariant (observably) is a bad implementation in the first place. The baggage of std::vector is all the functions the privately derived class will never use, like resize, move semantics, shink, amortized reallocations, etc.

Comment: I imagine a `FixedVector` that has a `unique_ptr<T[]>` and a `size_t m_size`, a friend could simply do `m_size = 1000;`. I agree that this would be a more obvious bug than `resize(1000);`, but I guess we can generally agree that one has to be very careful when implementing containers. Regarding the baggage, `FixedVector` inherits move semantics from `vector`, and the other functionality is simply not used (not even compiled) and shouldn't introduce overhead to `FixedVector`s functionality. But perhaps I'm bike shedding here :-)

Comment: _"based on `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`"_ - I'm pretty sure you don't mean inheritance here, but have to check. If you rephrase that so that it's obvious that you mean composition over inheritance, I'd support the idea.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I didn't specify because I am undecided :). In the spirit of the question, private inheritance from `std::unique_ptr` could reuse `operator[]` and some traits, like `pointer` and perhaps even `swap`. Any way it is secondary to my point.

Comment: @alfC No, the move operations are implicitly inherited. [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/xdMf8ezhn). Regarding the inherited move operations, it does not matter if `vector` is a base class or a data member. The default copy and move operations are implemented by element-wise copy or moves of all base classes and data members.

Comment: @chrysante, you are correct. FixedVector would need to delete the move constructor if that is the desired behavior. https://godbolt.org/z/jqT95GMTb .

Comment: @alfC Ah, now I get your point. You say that the vector has been resized by the move operation despite our efforts to disable resizing. I would take the stance, that the vector has not been resized, but the variable `v` (in the example) simply refers to a new (empty) vector and the vector previously referred to by `v` was moved into `test`, but it's size was not modified. But yes, I the desired behaviour is that each vector _object_ always has the same size, you would have to disable move operations and the assignment operators. That would be a weird design though.

Comment: @chrysante Yes, actually, all that can be said about the moved-from state can also be said also about the default construction, if any. In this case of a fixedvector, default construction implies the partially-formed state. Which, despite the name, is usually a good option.

Comment: @alfC  Thank you very much for your answer. May you answer my other question of detailed point one:
If I use the existing implementation, what can I do so that the `It` type only accepts arbitrary iterators of type `T`?
'Arbitrary' means that neither the type of the source container nor iterator constraints such as const or reversed matters.
Or is it impossible?
Thanks again to you and all the seniors who commented and answered.

Comment: @IsuxizSlidder, see my added note. In a few words, I don't recommend doing that. Taking generic It is good enough.